# Boundary conditions for the EM wave

Tags: electromagnetism

I am a lot confused in understanding  that What does the tangential component of electric field mean? How to visualize  this thing?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a medium 1 and medium 2 with boundary between then one can talk about the electric field in medium 1 and medium 2. These electric fields at the boundary can have a normal componenet(normal to the boundary) and a componenet perpendicular to this normal component which is called the tangential component. Boundary condition requires that the tangential component of E at the boundary be equal. That is that in medium 1 should be equal to that in medium 2.